# How can I use map and filter together to remove null values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
columnValueList(val) {
  return this.beacons.map((d) => d[val].name);
},
```

this is my function, is workingperfectly but sometimes i might get the name null. How can i filter the null value and map it?? I am getting center in val. I might get d[val].name null and trying tol remove the null from here and map it

My `this.beacons` structure:
[image: xxx]

Comment: What is this `val`parameter? This is inconsistent with your database sample. Looks like you want to extract an array of `center.name` values from `this.beacons`.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand things, you have a *list of lists of objects*, your `this.beacons`. You want to

1. Reduce the list of lists of objects to a flat list of objects by filtering each sublist by `val`, then...
2. Reduce that list of objects to a list of [presumably] string (the `name` property of each object), and
3. Discard anything where the `name` property is null.

So, the straightforward way would be:

```js
const columnValueList = v => this.beacons
  .map(    b => b[v]   ) // filter by `val`, reducing list-of-lists to a simple list
  .map(    o => o.name ) // map to just the `name` property of each object
  .filter( n => n      ) // discard falsy names; keep only truthy names
  ;
```

That requires 3 passes and 2 intermediary arrays to be created and populated. However, it's easy to optimize a bit:

```js
const columnValueList = v => this.beacons
  .map(    b => b[v].name ) // filter by v and map to 'name'
  .filter( n => n         ) // discard falsy names; keep only truthy names
  ;
```

That's 2 passes and 1 intermediate list created/populated.

Or you could kick it old-school (and more efficiently — 1 pass, no intermediates):

```js
const columnValuesList = v => {
  const list = [];

  for (const beacon of this.beacons ) {

    const d = d[v];
    if (d.name) {
      list.push(d.name);
    }

  }

  return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but Can you once look at the image i just posted! this.beacons is in that structure. I am trying to get only the centers name, but sometimes I get name empty

Answer (score -1):

The filter function actually returns an array with the filtered values. You only need filter, no mapping.

```
return this.beacons.map((d) => return d[val].name !== null);
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Pelicer's answer is not right.
should be

```
columnValueList(val) {
  return this.beacons.map((d) => d[val].name).filter(value => value);
},
```

Comment: because Array.prototype.map will always return an array with same length of the input array. and Array.prototype.filter will always return the original element of the input array. 

but the question is about picking some column of the original array and then filter them.

Comment: .I need to  filter the null values from the d[val].name and then map it
In val i am getting the center. I might get the center.name null sometimes and i am trying to remove the null value.